# animating dots in canvas, strange line behaviours with speed of dots > 1 by frame

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Trying to animate dots(imageData 1x1) on a javascript canvas to make a starfield.

The strange thing is when those dots move at a speed higher than 1, there is like a flickering or anything else showing not a dot but a line.

here is a fiddle to show the strangeness: http://jsfiddle.net/xp6xd8q1/1/

```
function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
}
function stars() {
    this.manyStars = [];

    this.addStars = function(nb) {
        var i,x,y;
        for(i=0;i<nb;i++) {
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            this.manyStars.push({x: x,y: y,s: 5});    // dot speed is s
        }
    }
    this.move = function() {
        var i,l;
        for(i=0,l = this.manyStars.length;i<l;i++) {
            this.manyStars[i].x = this.manyStars[i].x - this.manyStars[i].s;
            if(this.manyStars[i].x < 0) {
                this.manyStars[i].x = w + this.manyStars[i].x;
            }
        }
    }
    this.drawStars = function() {
        var i,l;
        for(i=0,l = this.manyStars.length;i<l;i++) {
            ctx.putImageData(dot,this.manyStars[i].x,this.manyStars[i].y);
        }
    }
}
function run() {
    clearCanvas();
    s.move();
    s.drawStars();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
//
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
var w =  window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;
cv.width = w;
cv.height = h;
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(cv);
//
var dot = ctx.createImageData(1,1);
dot.data = [255,255,255,255];
s = new stars();
s.addStars(10);
window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
```

Any idea on this is very welcomed !

Comment: to answer suppen and marke: first,  thanks for trying to elucidate that thing :p I already tried with fillrect and other things, with the same results. And putImageData vs fillrect is quite current here on stackoverflow ! A thing to notice is that if you 'pause' the scene (chrome tools for examples), dots are what they should be, that is, dots ! This strange thing appears only while animating, and only at a speed > 1. Even weirdest is if i draw a black dot where the white dot was, its even worse...

Comment: ok, i'll stick to the 'motion blur' thing, even if i'm not 100% in. Would have so much blur on any game !

Tried double buffering, creating img then moving it, animating divs, animating lines, putting longer img (dot then black), various dot erasing, and some other things, to the same result :/

Thanks for trying to help :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it too. The dots appear to be stretched when they move. I screenshotted the canvas at several speeds. The dots really are just 1x1 pixel.

I believe you may be experiencing [Display Motion Blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_motion_blur). It's a result of how displays work, and also because the vision cells in your eye take a bit of time to readjust when light changes.

There's not really much you can do about that, except try to hide it. It becomes less and less apparent the larger your moving objects are, and the slower they move.

It also becomes less apparent when the display refresh rate increases. See [this example](http://www.testufo.com/#test=framerates). Since you can't control the users' monitor's refresh rates, this doesn't really help you.

Comment: i thought about the motion blur thing, but if you use a speed of 10 (for example), the line is longer too...

Comment: @sliss. **Here's why**: When you pull the imageData leftward, the right size of the canvas is no longer covered by the imageData. So your previously drawn stars are not being erased and you are seeing multiple copies of a star appear horizontally across the canvas.

Comment: It's correct as stated in this answer, an "optical illusion" in form of display blur. Here's another way of drawing the stars guaranteeing them being 1x1: http://jsfiddle.net/xp6xd8q1/3/. The blur becomes more visible (as blur) when increasing the size of the dots (due to the increased contrast): http://jsfiddle.net/xp6xd8q1/4/